# PyCharm zsh shell does not have full user PATH variables if ZDOTDIR is set to a custom folder

Tags: shell, terminal, path, pycharm, zsh

My PyCharm zsh shell does not have full user PATH environment variables.

Currently, in PyCharm preferences, my shell path is `/bin/zsh`.

Custom config is set in `~/.zshenv`
`ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig`

It does not have any of the additional $PATH or aliases that I have added in my `~/zshconfig/.zprofile` or `~/zshconfig/.zshrc`.

Also, trying to run zsh as an interactive login shell from PyCharm also does not work. (setting PyCharm shell path to: `/bin/zsh --interactive --login` does not work)

**How do I run a normal terminal environment in PyCharm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is my third answer...

PyCharm does not follow ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig when set in your `~/.zshenv`

Unfortunately, PyCharm does not support the “FOO=bar /bin/zsh” notation, so we need a wrapper script to launch it.  [source](https://tompaw.net/pycharm-virtualenv-zsh-terminal/)

What we want to do is make PyCharm use our custom `$ZDOTDIR` directory.
Add a file in your home directory `~/pycharm_zsh.sh`:  *Change the '~/zshconfig' to the correct path for your configurations*

```
#!/bin/sh
export ZDOTDIR=~/zshconfig
/bin/zsh --login --interactive
```

Make that script executable:
`chmod +x ~/pycharm_zsh.sh`

In pycharm, set "Shell path" to your custom script:
`/Users/<username>/pycharm_zsh.sh`

Comment: The wrapper can be written slightly shorter as `ZDOTDIR=~/zshconfig /bin/zsh --login --interactive`. Since `/bin` is likely in the PATH anyway, you don't need to provide an absolute path to zsh. Since the zsh is connected to a tty, I guess that you don't need `--interactive`, as this should be the default; but this is certainly something you better test well.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer should apply to sh, bash, zsh, and fish shells**

The issue is that PyCharm has this option called "Shell integration".
To quote their website on the "Shell integration" option:

> Integrate the terminal with the system shell to properly keep track of your command history for sessions and load a custom config file with required environment variables.
>
> Shell integration works for sh, bash, zsh, and fish shells.
> [source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html)

What this does is create a custom shell environment (managed by PyCharm) that does NOT source your `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc`.
(FYI: `~/.zshenv` is sourced always)

**There are 3 options to add your environment variables.**

1. Disable the "Shell integration" option. This will launch a normal shell (--interactive --login) that PyCharm does not manage. This shell will be your normal user configurated shell.
2. Add your environment variables to PyCharm.
   In PyCharm terminal settings, you can add `PATH`: `<directory you want to add to path>:$PATH` as an Environment Variable. (This may be required for each project)
3. (**Not Recommended**) Export your $PATH variables in `.zshenv`.
   Add `export PATH="<directory you want to add to path>:$PATH"` to your `.zshenv` file.
   **This will be applied on any shell that runs!** Not just login and interactive shells.
   [zsh config files reference](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html#:%7E:text=zshenv%27%20is%20sourced%20on%20all,is%20attached%20to%20a%20tty.)
   [zsh config files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout)

Comment: I never worked with PyCharm, but it seems that you can [set environment variables in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm). If you define there a variable `PyCharm=YES`, you can then query this variable in your zsh startup files and apply certain settings only if run from a PyCharm terminal.

Comment: These files are never sourced by PyCharm itself, but by the zsh it starts, and of course can pass parameters to this Zsh, to influence the startup behaviour to a certain extent. Since you say that the `.zshenv` is processed, we can at lesat conclude that PyCharm did at least not fiddle with the ZDOTDIR variable, and since the resulting shell is interactive, `.zshrc` is sourced too. If you really think it won't be sourced (which looks like a bug to me), you can always source it manually.

Comment: @user1934428 That's an interesting idea. Set it in PyCharm then check for `PYTCHARM` in `. zshenv`. It it's true, source your `.zprofile` and `zshrc` manually?

Comment: @user1934428 I tested it on my Mac and `.zshrc` was not sourced by default.  Maybe this is just a bug

Comment: Only when run from within PyCharm? This would be odd. Otherwise, I am using zsh on the Mac too, and it works like advertised. How did you verify that your .zshrc was not processed?

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, only in PyCharm. I added a path with a command and also added `echo "interactive shell"` to `.zshrc`.  Neither worked when "Shell integration" is turned on. They work in a normal terminal though

Comment: I do have a custom zsh structure with the config files in a separate folder though. Maybe that doesn't work with PyCharm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220980/discussion-between-darin-and-user1934428).

Comment: That made me try something...
I moved my configs from `~/zshconfig` to `~/`. Then they worked fine!

For some reason, PyCharm appears to be reading `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zprofile` directly from the home directory even though `ZDOTDIR` is set.

In my `~/.zshenv` I have `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig`.
This works fine for normal terminals but apparently not for PyCharm... oof

Comment: I just fixed it another way...
I made a `~/.zshrc` in the home directory and sourced my file in the folder:

```# PyCharm reads this file directly, doesn't follow "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig"
echo "interactive shell (~/.zshrc)"

# If this file gets read directly:
source ~/zshconfig/.zshrc```

And did the same for `.zprofile`

Now it works fine even with "Shell integration" turned on!

Comment: Think about this from the viewpoint of zsh. If you read the zsh man-page, it is described clearly what it is doing when starting up, and what factors can have influence. Also, I wouldn't trace the startup process by placing `echo` commands here and there, but by getting a full trace via `set -x`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks! That's good to know. I'll try using `set - x` next time

Answer (score 0):

[My First Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710784/10439771)  was a workaround until I realized the actual issue was that PyCharm was not following `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig`.  My original solution still works but this appears to be the actual issue.

If the "Shell integration" option is turned on,
PyCharm does not follow `$ZDOTDIR`!
That means if you have your `.zshrc` in a custom folder (Ex. `~/zshconfig/.zshrc`, PyCharm will not read it.  PyCharm will just look in the default location, which is `~/.zshrc`.

**I would be curious if anyone has a way to have PyCharm follow your `$ZDOTDIR`!**

My better solution, for the time being, is to create a file in my home directory and source my custom file location.

Create the file that PyCharm reads directly `~/.zshrc`:

```
# For debugging which file gets sourced
#echo "interactive shell (~/.zshrc)"

# PyCharm reads this file directly, doesn't follow "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zshconfig"
# If this file gets read directly, source my custom location:
source ~/zshconfig/.zshrc
```

And respectively for `~/.zprofile`